# How to construct fmap for a newtype that houses functions

Tags: haskell, functor, newtype

So let's say I want to define a newtype that houses a function:

```
newtype Test m a = Test(m -> (a, m))
```

This could be used to house state of some sort.

Now let's say I would like to implement fmap for this newtype.

```
instance Functor (Test m) where
    --fmap :: (a -> b) -> Test m a -> Test m a -> b
    fmap f (Test f1) (Test f2) = ?
```

Since the newtype houses functions there's no way to use pattern matching to break f1 and f2 apart.

For instance I initially thought maybe I could pass the input value of f2 into the call f1 to yield a (a, m) tuple, but I don't think you can do that.
ie

```
tup = f1 (get input of f2)
```

Is anyone able to provide me with what concepts I'm missing to deal with this scenario or is this just not possible?

Thanks

**UPDATE**

Big thanks to Redu and Willem Van Onsem.

Looks like I was lacking in understanding of how to use the composition operator (.).

Basically the key here is use (.) to grab the first element of the tuple and then do a bunch of partial function definitions to get into the state needed by fmap. Here is my fmap implementation without using the library function. Purposefully verbose to help with understanding.

```
alterParamStateHelper :: (a -> b) -> (m -> a) -> m -> (b, m)
alterParamStateHelper f1 f2 m = (b, m)
  where 
    a = f2 e
    b = f1 a

alterParamState :: (a -> b) -> (m -> (a, m)) -> (m -> (b, m))
alterParamState f1 f2 = alterParamStateHelper f1 h1
  where
    h1 = fst . f2--m -> a

instance Functor (Test m) where
  -- fmap :: (a -> b) -> Test m a -> Test m b
  fmap f1 (Test f2) = Test (alterParamState f1 f2)
```

Comment: `fmap` does not take two `Test`s, it has signature `fmap :: (a -> b) -> Test m a -> Test m b` here.

Comment: `fmap` operator is defined at the Functor instance of the function type `(->) r`  as the composition operator `(.)`. In other words applying `f` to the result of that function. This should give you an idea.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Since the newtype houses functions there's no way to use pattern matching to break `f1` and `f2` apart.

There is a problem with your `fmap` signature here. `fmap` has signature [**`fmap :: Functor f => (a -> b) -> f a -> f b`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:fmap) so if `f ~ Test m`, then the signature is `fmap :: (a -> b) -> Test m a -> Test m b`.

We thus can here define an `fmap` where we "post-process" the result of the function. We thus construct a new function that will use the old function to construct a 2-tuple `(a, m)`, and then call `f` on the first item, such that we construct a tuple `(b, m)`:

```
import Control.Arrow(first)

instance Functor (Test m) where
    fmap f (Test g) = Test (first f . g)
```

Comment: Thanks! To be sure I fully understood all the concepts at play here I added my own solution to the original question without using Arrow. Does my solution look valid?

Comment: @mBrice1024: without the `first`, you can write it as `fmap f (Test g) = Test (\x -> let (a, b) = g x in (f a, b))`

Comment: Nice, way more concise. I forgot about let, in.